# archtechx / tenancy vs spatie / laravel-multitenancy

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, multi-tenant

I'm implementing multi Tenancy architecture in laravel first time for a multi-vendor eCommerce application and I've came across two packages for tenancy management, [archtechx / tenancy](https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy) and [spatie / laravel-multitenancy](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/tree/main). I wasn't able to find core differences between the two packages. My app will be API based and would not differentiate databases of tenants based on the sub-domain system. Can you please advise regarding the main differences between both packages and which one is best for the use case?